# Why am I getting an error while creating a delta table having a default value in databricks , its showing its not possible to do this?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

So I was trying to create a table having a default value for timestamp, and it's giving me the below error :

[image]

```
error :- AnalysisException: Failed to execute CREATE TABLE command because DEFAULT values are not supported for target data source with table provider: "delta"
```

I don't know what else to try, is there a way to mimic this ?

Comment: error :- 
AnalysisException: Failed to execute CREATE TABLE command because DEFAULT values are not supported for target data source with table provider: "delta"

Comment: You should include the actual code and not an image of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [generated column](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/generated-columns.html) for that:

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS (current_timestamp()),
```

Update: See comment from Ian - `current_timestamp` couldn't be used as generated column.  It should be `now()`, but with the warning.

Comment: Returns "Current_timestamp() cannot be used in a generated column" error, at least for recent versions.   now() will work, however apparently that is a bug as they do not want to allow non-deterministic functions for generated columns.   If you use now(), any attempt to UPDATE or DELETE will fail.

Comment: Hmmm, what Delta / DBR version are you using?

Comment: Latest version 13.0

Comment: ah, you're correct, my bad...

Answer (score 0):

It also works with DEFAULT keyword when you add TBLPROPERTIES clause as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE timestamp (
  name STRING, 
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT now())
  USING DELTA
  **TBLPROPERTIES('delta.feature.allowColumnDefaults' = 'supported' );
```